# In firefox private window facebook profile picture not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a wordpress website and used social login/register. All going good, but if i open any account created with facebook login in firefox private window, it does not display profile picture.
[See screenshot.](http://prntscr.com/izqoxz)

It happens only in private window.

Please help.

Comment: Firefox blocks Facebook functionality in a private window, when tracking protection is enabled. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226498

Comment: @CBroe - So any solution to fix it?

Comment: Apart from not using private windows if you want the functionality ... no.